# send login request to server using jquery POST method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want to log into this website: https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in 
I sent log in credentials to the website form using POST method and request login as a response.
However it does not work. I get redirected to login page when i click button.
Is there something wrong with the code?

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Approach to Login</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://jinji.jinjer.biz/assets/templates/hr/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async="" src="//wap.wovn.io/1.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in",{

    company_code:"5709",
    email:"1234",
    password:"1234"
    },function (data) {

   　　　 window.open("https://kintai.jinjer.biz/staffs/top");
        });

    });

});

</script>

</head>

<body>
<button type= "submit"> Login </button>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding prevent default.

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post("https://kintai.jinjer.biz/sign_in",{
        company_code:"5709",
        email:"1234",
        password:"1234"
    },function (data) {
    　　　 window.open("https://kintai.jinjer.biz/staffs/top");
    });
});
```

Comment: When I use function (data) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data ); I get a 404 error